# How to set DesignInstance to a ViewModel from c++ cli

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, c++-cli

Is it somehow possible to specify a ViewModel written in c++ cli as Xaml datacontext DesignInstance in WPF/MVVM pattern?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft added a new feature to VS 2019 16.8 that allows you to set d:DataContext for use in the designer.  You just have to set an xml namespace to the dotnet namespace and assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.8 - XAML Code Editor - Improving MVVM Support.

That might work